# How to access z3c.form widget settings from browser view

Tags: plone, dexterity, z3c.form

Given following widget based on z3c.form https://github.com/collective/Products.UserAndGroupSelectionWidget/blob/z3cform-widget/src/Products/UserAndGroupSelectionWidget/z3cform/widget.py

I would like in some browserview to access its settings and corresponding field. Since Widget does not know the schema and field upfront, I'm interested in what information do I need to get widget and field. Currently I have available the fieldname and context, which seemed to be enough for archtypes https://github.com/collective/Products.UserAndGroupSelectionWidget/blob/z3cform-widget/src/Products/UserAndGroupSelectionWidget/browser.py#L60

**EDIT:** To simplify the question, I would like to **access a field** that is defined in some **z3c form** and its widget. I could not find other way except passing request and context to form init and then accessing the field. Is there a multiadapter?

The idea is to have a z3c.form widget that people hook into whatever field which does an ajax call. That ajax request needs to pass parameters and response will lookup where widget was used and with what settings. The question is, **how** to lookup the z3c.form field and which **information** is needed to do so?

Comment: Following two lines need to be adjusted so that code will work with any form: https://github.com/collective/Products.UserAndGroupSelectionWidget/blob/z3cform-widget/src/Products/UserAndGroupSelectionWidget/browser.py#L70

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Getting the Field**

If you can get the schema, you can get the field.

For a dexterity content type, if you know the field name and the type's portal_type, you can get the schema from the type's **Factory Type Information** (**FTI**).

So, if we know **portal_type** and **field_name**:

```
from zope.component import getUtility
from plone.dexterity.interfaces import IDexterityFTI
fti = getUtility(IDexterityFTI, name=portal_type)
schema = fti.lookupSchema()
field = schema.get(field_name)
```

**Getting the Widget**

From the z3c.form documentation: http://packages.python.org/z3c.form/widget.html

The widget is a multiadapter, so if you have the field, you can get it like so:

```
ageWidget = zope.component.getMultiAdapter((field, request),
    interfaces.IFieldWidget)
```

**Important:** If you have however specified a widget via *plone.autoform*, then that widget won't be fetched. *plone.autoform* manually sets a *widgetFactory* on the *z3c.form.field.Field* object (which is not the same as the *zope.schema* Field!). The best way to get the widget then, is what you have already done, by manually calling initiating a **FieldWidget**.

So for example if you want the *UserAndGroupSelectionWidget*:

```
widget = FieldWidget(field, UserAndGroupSelectionWidget(field, request))
```

*P.S Since I'm also in the collective and use the picker widget, I've updated the code for you* ;)

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks! I somehow smelled dexterity needs to be involved and it's not possible with plain z3c.form.